# Prove a function on the set of propositional formulas is well-defined

Tags: induction, propositional-calculus, recursion

I define the set $X$ of propositional formulas as the smallest set such that:

1. Every atomic formula is in $X$.
2. If $F$ is in $X$ then $\neg F$ is in $X$.
3. If $F$ and $G$ is in $X$ than $(F\land  G ), (F\lor G) $ and $(F \rightarrow G)$ is in $X$.

Let $t$ be a function from the atomic formulas to $\{0,1\}$. A valuation can be defined recursively as

1. $\nu (P)=1$ if and only if $t(p)=1$ for all atomic formulas.
2. $\nu(\neg F)=1$ iff $\nu( F)=0$
3. $\nu((F\land G))=1$ iff $\nu(F)=1$ and $\nu(G)=1$
4. $\nu((F\lor G))=1$ iff $\nu(F)=1$ or $\nu(G)=1$
5. $\nu((F\rightarrow G))=1$ iff $\nu(F)=0$ or $\nu(G)=1$

But how do I know that $\nu$ is well-defined? The reason I am asking is that when defining the set $X$ a formula $F$ can arise many different times, so I must be sure that every time it arises I give it the same value. Do you see how to prove this? I suspect I must use an induction proof, but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: @DanielSchepler yes

Comment: "$F$ can arise many times." Actually, it can't, but this is a non-trivial theorem, often referred to as "unique readability". This theorem (and the consequent well-definedness of inductive constructions like $v$) are the reason parentheses are included in the construction rules for formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every formula in $X$ can be formed in exactly one way; this is obvious from your formation rules. You would use induction in the structure of formulae or, equivalently, induction in the size of formulae, showing that for for every $n \geq 1$, if $F$ has size $n$, then there is exactly one $b \in \{ 0,1\}$ such that $v(F) = b$.

Comment: Thank you. Is this correct?:By definition every atomic formula is defined in only one way. I assume that for n greater or equal to one every formula is well defined. A formula of size n+1 can only be created one way of formulas less than n+1 so it has only one valuation?

Comment: I mean that every formula greater than 1 and less than or equal to n, for n greater or equal to 1 is well defined.

Comment: The *size* of a formula is the number of connectives used to build it. A formula of size $n+1$ is built from immediate constituents whose size is at most $n$ (in the case of negation). By induction hypothesis, the value of each such immediate constituent is unique.